# browse ftp file in firefox browser linux

Tags: html, linux, firefox, upload, ftp

I want to set users upload file to my server in browser. I use `<input type="file" />` for upload file.

Some of my users want to upload file from ftp server to my server. In windows this users can set ftp URL in address bar and select file to upload, but Linux users can't upload file from ftp with file browse.

How can my Linux users upload files from ftp to my server with input HTML tag? Or how can my Linux users access ftp from file browser? Note that my users use Firefox.

Comment: `ftp://example.com` - this doesn't show a directory tree?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @odedta. i need set ftp URL to address in Firefox open dialogues in Linux and Firefox save dialogues show me ftp files to select file in ftp for upload. my upload to server correctly work.

Comment: Are you saying that Firefox linux doesn't allow file uploaded via browser in using FTP?

Comment: Just to give you an example: I'm on Windows 7 and logged in to my ftp account using Google Chrome browser, this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/qAthB4S.jpg - There is no where to upload a file there.

Comment: @odedta I don't say "Firefox linux doesn't allow file uploaded via browser in using FTP". and i say how can i browse file from ftp with input file HTML element. this work in windows. but i don't know how do in Linux.

Comment: see this: http://www.refining-linux.org/uploads/content-img/open-dialog-with-icons.png. i want to open ftp in this panel. how can i get ftp i this panel?

Comment: You need to install an FTP client I assume.

Comment: `how can i browse file from ftp with input file HTML element` - FTP directory tree view - like the one I showed you before cannot contain HTML input elements since it's not really an HTML file, it's just a presentation of folders on the server.

Comment: browse file from ftp with input file HTML element worked for me in windows. so i say maybe it has a way that work in Linux.

Comment: Can you show a live link with example? you mean that if you open up Google Chrome on Windows and type in `ftp://example.com/` you see an HTML upload input and you can upload files through there??

Comment: i want to upload file **from** ftp **to** my server. with client that it is between my server and ftp.

Comment: Dear friend, FTP means File Transfer Protocol, so it's essentially a protocol. I guess you want to ask: "How do I transfer files between my computer and my server using FTP" - For that, you need FTP software(client) https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1

Comment: The question is asking how to select files from an FTP server using the file picker dialog associated with a file input on an HTML page (a feature built-in to the standard Windows File Picker dialogue). After the file is picked from the FTP server, it will be uploaded via HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for a webpage author to control what filesystems will be made available via the File Input dialogue. That comes down entirely to browser support (which generally just uses the system file picker dialogue).

If you want to explicitly provide a mechanism, then you would need for the FTP server to be accessible to the web server and to write a web application frontend to it. Users could then use that instead of a File Input.

Comment: OK. thanks a lot. so how can i write a mechanism that access FTP? i try use XMLHttpRequest for get list of file from FTP and get error from same origin policy.

Comment: Pick a server side programming language. Find an FTP library for it. Design a UI. Write the application.